# Plot Markers for plot in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I want to have two plot with

```
PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSquare]"}, {"\[FivePointedStar]"}}
```

I wrote this code:

```
a := Sin[x]
b := Cos[x]
Plot[{a, b}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSquare]"}, {"\[FivePointedStar]"}}]
```

But I do not have output. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: (1) Plot is misspelled in your code. (2) `PlotMarkers` is not an option for `Plot`, but for `ListPlot` and its siblings.

Comment: Maybe you're after something like `a = Sin[Range[0., 1., 0.1]]; b = Cos[Range[0., 1., 0.1]]; ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", "\[FivePointedStar]"}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had spelled `Plot` correctly, *Mathematica* would have told you that `PlotMarkers` is not a valid option for `Plot` by highlighting it in red.

[image: input]

I suspect that what you really want is something like

```
data = Transpose @ Table[{{x, Sin[x]}, {x, Cos[x]}}, {x, Subdivide[N[2 π], 16]}];
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", "\FivePointedStar]"}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: If possible for you, I want connect "\[FilledSquare]" with line,

Comment: And I want to use arbitrary color for each function.

Comment: @user37694 please read up on the documention of `ListPlot` and related. It is all there, lots of nice examples you can immediately work with.